# Is there a better way to add leading zeros to a int in dart and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an extension for the dart int to add leading zeros and I am wondering if there is a more elegant way? My take on it:

```
extension IntExtensions on int {
  ///returns a String with leading zeros.
  ///1 would be with the [numberOfTotalDigits] = 3 lead to a string '001'
  String addLeadingZeros(int numberOfTotalDigits) {
    var valueAsString = this.toString();
    var buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (valueAsString.length < numberOfTotalDigits) {
      var addLeadingZeros = numberOfTotalDigits - valueAsString.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < addLeadingZeros; i++) buffer.write('0');
    }
    return '${buffer.toString()}$valueAsString';
  }
}
```

Unit test:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:utilities/extensions/int_extensions.dart';

void main() {
  test('test addLeadingZeros int extension', () {
    int a = 1;
    expect(a.addLeadingZeros(5), equals('00001'));
    expect(a.addLeadingZeros(1), equals('1'));
    expect(a.addLeadingZeros(2), equals('01'));
    expect(a.addLeadingZeros(3), equals('001'));
    expect(a.addLeadingZeros(0), equals('1'));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
extension IntExtensions on int {
  ///returns a String with leading zeros.
  ///1 would be with the [numberOfTotalDigits] = 3 lead to a string '001'
  String addLeadingZeros(int numberOfTotalDigits) =>
      toString().padLeft(numberOfTotalDigits, '0');
}
```